# C++ Help: Error: lvalue required as increment operand

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, lvalue, pre-increment, operands

What is wrong here. What does it mean by the error: lvalue required as increment operand?
(NOTE: this is a textbook example)

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

   int main()
  {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 10, result;
    
    num1++;
    
    result = ++(num1 + num2);
    
    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless your book uses that as an example of something that's wrong, the book is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `++x` is called preincrement operator while `x++` is called postincrement.
Both need a modifiable 'lvalue' variable as the operand. In this case `x` is the 'lvalue'.

If you have a code `y = ++x` it has the same semantic meaning as

```
x = x + 1;
y = x;
```

So this specific code `++(num1 + num2)` is actually making the error because `num1 + num2` is not a valid modifiable variable and the semantic of `result = ++(num1 + num2)` will be:

```
num1 + num2 = (num1 + num2) + 1; // this is invalid
result = num1 + num2;
```

You can fix it as:

```
int x = num1 + num2;
result = ++x;
```

Or the shorter version, that produces the same result:

```
++(result = num1 + num2)
```